# When to use tf.Variable vs TensorArray

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

I do have a beginners questions to the usage of tensorflow tensor objects.

I am misusing tensorflow for calculating gradients for some algorithm which is far from being matrix multiplications. I am aware of the fact that this is most likely a bad idea - I still want to try it.

I want to assign results of intermediate computations to elements of a tensor in order to pass it on to the next layer. 
Since I am not capable of computing the entire result tensor as a whole in one operation I want to assign the results elemtwise, which I think should be ok to do if I understand the docu correctly.

Apparently I can do that by either using a tf.Variable or a TensorArray. Both allow dynamic assignment of values during runtime while allowing gradients to be computed through them.

What is the difference between the two in the described (mis)usecase and what would be the recommended choice here?

Best,
N.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

tf.variable is a basic type of tensor which is mutable. The Variable() constructor requires an initial value for the variable, which can be a Tensor of any type and shape. This initial value defines the type and shape of the variable. After construction, the type and shape of the variable are fixed. The value can be changed using the assign methods.

tf.TensorArray class is meant to be used with dynamic iteration primitives such as while_loop and map_fn.

Both allow dynamic assignment and in your case either can be used. But TensorArray of defined type is better approach to use as tf.variable creates a tensor which is of assigned variable type.

Comment: Just in case anone else stumbles over this: I experimented with both options and found only the TensorArray to actually track the gradients through the dynamic assignments. Thanks for your comment though!